# Share Memory on demand

Tags: c++

I would like to know if it is possible to ask a process to share a part of its memory on demand.

Here is my case (I haven't begun to code except for the simulation part)

I would like to build a [CFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics) software as a service. 
The idea is people would go to a website and run simulations, and the progress could be viewed in real time (a graph updating itself while the simulation runs).

So I have one process, which is the web application (I am thinking of writing it with cppCMS), and it would be responsible of launching another process, which would do the simulation. The real time diplay of the solution would be done by use of shared memory between the web application and the simulation software.

Once the user closes the tab in its browser, I'd like the simulation process to continue running, obviously.

The tricky part comes when the user returns. The web application should ask the simulation process to share its memory, and retrieve the data about the simulation progress.

I'd like to know if what I want to do is feasible, and if it is, some links towards how to's would be great.

Also, I am quite new to programming, and maybe the solution I want to implement here is not the best. If you have some suggestions on how to do it better, they are very welcome :)

[EDIT] I thought of writing the progress to a database, but I think the writing process after each calculation would be a bottle neck in terms of performance. The best solution would be the most little or no overhead at all.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably want a database.

Comment: boost provides quite a good cross-platform wrapper for inter-process shared memory - it makes life a lot easier than using platform-specific APIs for this kind of thing.

Comment: This is operating system specific. You might consider [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)

Comment: I would be very surprised if 'shared memory' is the right strategy for this.  I don't expect you want to use a database, either.  I think the clue is in the words 'as a service'... you probably want to implement some "restful service" that yields your results.  Of course - the right approach depends greatly upon the type of calculations you are doing and how you plan to present the results in the web-app. If you draw a simple graph using a javascript library, such as D3, the service might only need to generate some JSON data.  More complex graphs might be created as a series of PNG images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IPC / Message Queues / Named pipes ([link](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html) / [link](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=292)) or (better in my opinion) use [Sockets](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm).